# getElementsByTagName("td") doesn't return all td children for a selected row

Tags: javascript, dom

I've created a javascript function that invert rows and columns of a table. Here is the code :

```
function rotate(){
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var newtable = document.createElement("table");

            var tablebody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var newtablebody = document.createElement("tbody");
            newtable.appendChild(newtablebody);

            var rows = tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            var heads = tablebody.getElementsByTagName("th");

            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
            {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                var j;
                for(j = 0; j < heads.length; j++)
                {
                    if(newtablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j] == undefined)
                    {
                        var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
                        newtablebody.appendChild(newrow);
                    }
                    if(cells[j] == undefined)
                    {
                        var newcell = document.createElement("td");
                        newtablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].appendChild(newcell);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newcell = cells[j];
                        var nbspan = cells[j].getAttribute("colspan");
                        newcell.setAttribute("rowspan", nbspan);
                        newcell.setAttribute("colspan", 1);
                        newtablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].appendChild(newcell);
                    }
                }
            }
            table.innerHTML = newtable.innerHTML;
        };
```

The problem is that when I try to get all children with tag name "td" for the current row, I get a lot of undefined cells, whereas I can see from the console log that these cells exist and contain data (I display innerHTML in the log).

I'm really lost, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure that `table`, `tablebody`, etc are all non-null?

Comment: If you put some HTML in here it would be much easier to test your script.

Comment: Yes, I've checked several times with console.log(table.innerHTML) and such, to make sure. 
Actually I know they are non-null because some <td> children are retrieved, but some are not, that's why I'm confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append an existing cell to the new table row, you implicitly *remove* it from the old table row; a cell can only be in one place in the DOM at a time. The node list that is returned by `getElementsByTagName()` is *live*, which means that removing that cell from the table row *also* immediately removes it from the `cells` array. That means that the cell that was at `cells[j]` is suddenly gone, and `cells[j]` thus becomes the *next* cell in the (old) table row. Your loop, however, still increments `j`, so you skip a cell whenever that happens.

One simple way to get past the problem is to copy the node list into an array before you start the loop:

```
   var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
   cells = [].map.call(cells, Object);
```

Now you've got a plain array, and elements won't magically disappear from it.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks a lot, that solved my problem!